# How to declare a class variable without a value in a way that suppresses Pylance warning

Tags: python, python-typing, pylance, vscode-python

I love the typechecker in Pylance (VS Code), but there seems to be a situation that I must choose between ignoring a Pylance warning and best practice for class variable declaration.
Many times, class variables are initialized using a `None` type in the class constructor, and the variable is set later. For example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.name:str = None

    def setName(self, name:str) -> None:
        self.name = name
```

In this case, Pylance gives the following error on the assignment `self.name:str = None`:

```
Cannot assign member "name" for type "Person"
Expression of type "None" cannot be assigned to member "name" of class "Person"
Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "str"
```

Is there any way to declare `self.name` in the constructor in such a way that a value is not needed *and* Pylance is happy?

EDIT: Several have suggested the use of `typing.Optional` to suppress this Pylance warning. However, if another member function is created to return `self.name` and guarantee that it is returning an instance of `str`, another Pylance error is generated. See the following example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._name:Optional[str] = None

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name:str) -> None:
        self._name = name
```

In this case, Pylance generates the error:

```
(variable) _name: str | None
Expression of type "str | None" cannot be assigned to return type "str"
Type "str | None" cannot be assigned to type "str"
Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "str"
```

Ideally, there would be some way to initially "allocate" `self._name` in the constructor in such a way that its only allowed type is `str` but is not given any value. Is this possible?

Comment: `: Optional[str] = None`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update**: This is so obvious I assume it won't work in your case, but it is the "natural thing to do"

If you arte annotating instance attributes, and don't want them to be able to read "None" or other sentinel value, simply *do not fill in* a sentinel value, just declare the attribute and its annotation. That is, do not try to fill in a value in `__init__`, declare the annotation in the class body instead:

```
class Person:

    name: str

    # No need for this:
    # def __init__(self) -> None:
    #    self.name:str = None

    def setName(self, name:str) -> None:
        self.name = name
```

---

Assuming you need to initialize it with an invalid value for whatever reason, the original answer applies:

Well, if this was certainly a case were the programmer knows better than the type-checker, I think it would be the case for using `typing.cast`: this is a no-operation in runtime, but which tells the static checkers that the value being `cast` is actually of that type, regardless of previous declarations:

(to be clear: **don't do this**:)

```
import typing as t

class Person:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._name: t.Optional[str, None] = None

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return t.cast(str, self._name)

    ...
```

However, upon writing this, I came to the realisation that "self._name" might actually **be** "None" at this time. The typechecker can do some state-checking by following the program steps, but not in such a generic way - trying to read `instance.name` before it was set should cause in Python a runtime error instead.

So, if the method is called to express exactly that, it works as the tools can follow parts of the code guarded by `isinstance` (and if one needs a more complicated check than `isinstance`, take a look on the docs for `typing.TypeGuard`) - and we thank the tools for ensuring the program will run without a hard to debug error afterwards:

(**this is the correct way**)

```py
import typing as t

class Person:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._name: t.Optional[str, None] = None

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        if isinstance(name:=self._name, str):
            return name
        raise AttributeError()

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name:str) -> None:
        self._name = name
```

Comment: `if self._name is not None` can serve as type guard too (instead of `isinstance`, maybe more appropriate here).

Comment: I know the tools recognize a call to "isinstance" as a way to narrow types in a code path. Not sure the same happens with "is None" check - but "not isinstance(var, NoneType)" should work.

Comment: `mypy` is absolutely happy with `is (not) None` (5th example [here in docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html?highlight=is%20None#additional-types-and-the-typing-module), [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=bc7e83dfe32c21c33b6bee1243f2f27a))

Answer (score 5):

You need to make it optional via [`typing.Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from typing import Optional


class Person:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.name: Optional[str] = None

    def setName(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
```

Python 3.10+ supports a simpler syntax via [PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/)'s [Union type expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-union)[1](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/#:%7E:text=Optional%20values%20should%20be%20equivalent%20to%20the%20new%20union%20syntax), e.g.:

```py
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.name: str | None = None
```

Comment: in 3.10+ also like `str | None`, which is bit more readable imo

Comment: Thanks! I'm in 3.9, so Optional is perfect. Good note about the alternate expression in 3.10.